# Getting useful git diff output between branches after a file has been renamed

Tags: git, version-control

I'm trying to diff a file in another branch, that was renamed. I've renamed the file back to its original name, using

```
git mv renamed.file original.file
git add -u original.file
git commit
```

this looks right in the tree, i.e. it keeps the history.

however, when I do a `git diff` between the file in two branches I am simply getting all of file a and all of file b - not a very useful diff output.

is there a way of getting a more fine-grained diff in this case?

I have tried: `git diff -C`, `git diff -M`, `git diff --follow -M` and `-M` with different percentages e.g. `-M10%` - in each case I get the same output

EDIT - Extra info that would have helped to solve the issue quicker: 
**The file was renamed and edited on Windows and I am on OSX**. (different line endings).

Comment: Did you heavily alter the file in the same commit as you renamed it?

Comment: Do you have `git config core.autocrlf` returning true?

Comment: @Zeeker yes it was modified quite a bit but still has many shared lines e.g. class declaration and imports

Comment: Lower the threshold below 10%.

Comment: @VonC ```git config core.autocrlf``` returns 1 (which in bash I think means failed/false?)

Comment: It could be possible that the changes were too much for git to detect a rename. You can always compare two files directly with each other. I'll add an answer explaining that.

Comment: @JosephK.Strauss I even tried ```-M1%``` and still the same...

Comment: So basically... just set git config core.autocrlf to false, as I thought all along.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of trying to convince git that a rename happend, you could just "force" it to compare the two files.

*I'll assume that you renamed the file in your last commit.*

To address a file directly - even if this file only exists in a different branch/commit - you can use the `<reference>:<path>` syntax. Taking advantage of this syntax a `diff` command could look like this:

```
git diff HEAD^:renamed.file original.file
```

Using this command you can compare the `renamed.file` from the previous commit (`HEAD^`) with the `original.file` of your current *working tree*.

---

You can take a look at the [`git rev-parse`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html#_specifying_revisions) documentation for details on the `<reference>:<path>` syntax.

---

### Still no success?

If you are still recieving the same output it's possible that you have whitespace changes which let git consider the lines as changed.

In such a case you can pass `git diff` further options to ignore whitespace changes:

- `--ignore-space-change` or just `-b` will ignore all whitespace changes; alternativly you can use
- `--ignore-space-at-eol` which will, as the name implies, only ignore whitespace changes at the end of the line

Take a look at the [`git diff` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html) for further details.

Comment: Did not know you could do git diff like this. Much simpler than my answer.

Comment: The file I want to compare (that was renamed, then put back to original name) is in the master branch, and I am in a feature branch. I tried ```git diff master:<filename> <filename>``` and still get the same output.

Comment: @Adamski You could try `git diff --ignore-space-change master:<filename> <filename>`. Maybe the line endings changed.

Comment: If you only want to ignore line endings changes you can use `git diff --ignore-space-at-eol master:<filename> <filename>`.

Comment: @Zeeker yes that gives me better output, and yes line endings look like they've changed. Adding options ```--ignore-space-at-eol -b -w``` solved my issue.

Comment: @Adamski I'll edit my answer to include that and would be grateful if you mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
git cat-file -p COMMIT:path/to/new/location > NEW
git cat-file -p COMMIT~1:path/to/old/location > OLD
diff OLD NEW
```

to see how different they actually are.

Also, try the --find-copies-harder option